# Error while doing Sign in with facebook iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

This is my second question about posting on Facebook :) Although this may be a duplicate.

After searching, i found one code sample for integrating with facebook

Here is my code snippet:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/afy97wvdyd2gdsn/FacebookTutorial.zip

When i add my `AppID` and `Client Key` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method it shows me **ERROR: remote_app_id does not match stored id. This may be caused by a mismatch between the bundle identifier and your app configuration on the server at developers.facebook.com/apps.**

Where i am doing mistake ?

***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your Bundle Identifier at [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

Under Edit Settings > Under Native iOS App add Bundle ID and try after 5 min

Comment: Yes, i have added Bundle Identifier as `com.Appname`

Comment: then app you are running is having same profile as mentioned bundle identifier

Answer (score 1):

The Bundle ID of the app has to match the one you input on the Facebook app Dashboard on Facebook developer website. Go again through step 4 on the [Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) guide.

Comment: Yes, i have added Bundle Identifier as `com.Appname` but it gives me error like, `Error Domain=com.parse.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x9929420 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401}`